# Transforming an n-column file to a single-column file

Tags: perl, shell

I have a file like this

```
chr1:752426-753176_NR_015368_LOC643837 chr1:752515-753265_NR_024321_NCRNA00115
```

Where separation is with a tab, it has n number of columns and n number of rows.

What I want to do is to have one single column of my whole data. like this

```
chr1:752426-753176_NR_015368_LOC643837 
chr1:752515-753265_NR_024321_NCRNA00115
```

Is there any one-liner in shell or Perl that can help me achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\t/\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

- Use the `-a` flag to split `@F` on columns
- `print` or `say` each element of `@F`
- Use `>` to redirect output to a new file *or* use the `-i` flag to enable in-place editing.

  ```
  $ perl -anE 'say for @F' input.txt > output.txt
  ```

Comment: The only reason why I haven't put a one-liner together is the lack of evidence that the OP took a stab at the problem. Once I see it I will post.

Comment: perl -F'/\s/' -lane '$,="\t"; print @F, for splice @F' $FILE     ........ something like this

Comment: Effort seen, one-liner posted